# Infinite product of limit elements.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinite-product

Suppose I have an array of strictly positive elements $\{a_{k}^{m}\}_{k,m\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that

1. $$ a_k:= \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}a_{k}^{m}  > 0 $$
2. $$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{m}a_{k}^{m} = 0 $$

Is convergence of $a_{k}^{m} \rightarrow a_k$ uniform over $k$ enough to ensure that 
$$
\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{m}a_{k} = 0 .
$$

Comment: A sufficient condition would be uniform convergence of $P_{mn} = \prod_{k=1}^na_k^m$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}.$  It seems you have moved on here.  Let me know if you want to see how this might work.

Comment: Thank you for the intuition. I think I see how this would work. This gives me hope again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform convergence of $a_k^m \to a_k$ is not sufficient. Consider

$$a_k^m = 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k+1}\sqrt{m+1}}.$$

Then $a_k^m \to 1$ uniformly, but

$$\sum_{k = 1}^m \log a_k^m < -\sum_{k = 1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k+1}\sqrt{m+1}} \sim -\frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{(m+1)^{2/3}}{\sqrt{m+1}} = -\frac{3}{2}(m+1)^{1/6} \to -\infty,$$

so

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \prod_{k = 1}^m a_k^m = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! Do you have any intuition about another sufficient condition that might ensure the result?

Comment: There's the rather trivial sufficient condition that $a_k^m \downarrow a_k$. I guess you're not in a situation where that applies. I don't know a nontrivial sufficient condition off the top of my head. Let me think about it for a moment.

Comment: I'm starting to realise that this problem is much harder than I anticipated beforehand. Thank you for your time invested.